# evaluation of variables inside a String

Tags: java, string, evaluation

I need to use String type to pass a bunch of setting options to an API method. The options inside that string, however, are supposed to change in every loop so that I can find the most proper ones. Like:

```
Options = "-C number1 -L number2 -P 1.0E-12 -N 0 -V -1 -W 1";
```

I want to change number1 and number2 every loop, but it seems that the variables inside a String cannot be evaluated, they're just treated as strings "number1" and "number2". So I'd like to know how I can evaluate them. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Evaluate in what sense?

Comment: what loop?  what do you mean "evaluate"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this:

```
int number1 = 234;
int number2 = 99;
System.out.println( String.format("-C %d -L %d -P 1.0E-12 -N 0 -V -1 -W 1", number1, number2) );
```

yields:

```
-C 234 -L 99 -P 1.0E-12 -N 0 -V -1 -W 1
```

So in your case:

```
String options = String.format("-C %d -L %d -P 1.0E-12 -N 0 -V -1 -W 1", number1, number2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Integer.parseInt(String numberInStringFormat)` to convert a `String` to an `Integer` type.

Comment: that's all the answer?

Comment: @Wagner What do you mean?